# Vertically Align Captions of Listings inside Table

Tags: tables, listings, captions, vertical-alignment

I have the following problem:
The LaTeX code below produces the output in the picture.

```
\usepackage{listings, tabularx, caption}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Vergleich von C++ und Swift Code}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | X | X | }

\hline
\lstinputlisting[style=table, caption={C++ Code}]{code/hello_world.cpp} & \lstinputlisting[style=table, caption={C Code}]{code/hello_world.c}\\
\hline

\end{tabularx}\par
\bigskip
Caption
\end{table}
```

[image]

Is there a way to vertically align the captions of the two code examples?

Comment: It would be a lot easier if your captions were not part of the \lstinputlisting.  Could you create a listing that consisted of just the caption?

Answer (score 2):

As you are presenting the listings within a table, you could start a new line for the subcaptions.

I personally think, you are using to many captions.  In your example you have a caption above the table, subcaptions beneath the listings and another (useless) caption below the table.  In my example, I removed the last one.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{listings, tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \caption{Vergleich von C++ und Swift Code}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | X | X | }
    \hline
    \lstinputlisting{code/hello_world.cpp} 
    & \lstinputlisting{code/hello_world.c}\\
    %% NEW: the following line contains the requested subcaptions, 
    %% being set on one line.
    \parbox{\linewidth}{\centering C++-Beispiel} 
    & \parbox{\linewidth}{\centering C-Beispiel} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

And the outcome:

[image]